# Как с генерировать исходный код из байтов?

Tags: java, файлы, декомпиляция

Имеется массив из байтов одной Java программы. Как мне получить её исходники в нормальном Java виде, с помощью ASM может как-то ?

Вот так выглядит массив (он намного больше, просто не вмещается сюда):

```
public static int[] classLoaderInBytes = {
            0xCA,0xFE,0xBA,0xBE, 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x34, 0x01,0x40,0x0A,0x00, 0x15,0x00,0x9F,0x07,
            0x00,0xA0,0x07,0x00, 0xA1,0x0A,0x00,0x03, 0x00,0x9F,0x08,0x00, 0xA2,0x0A,0x00,0xA3,
            0x00,0xA4,0x0A,0x00, 0x03,0x00,0xA5,0x09, 0x00,0xA6,0x00,0xA7, 0x08,0x00,0xA8,0x0A,
            0x00,0x03,0x00,0xA9, 0x08,0x00,0xAA,0x0A, 0x00,0x02,0x00,0xAB, 0x08,0x00,0xAC,0x0A,
            0x00,0x02,0x00,0xAD, 0x0A,0x00,0x02,0x00, 0xAE,0x0A,0x00,0x15, 0x00,0xAF,0x0B,0x00
};
```

Конвертирую в байт массив:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[classLoaderInBytes.length];
for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++){
     bytes[i] =  (byte)classLoaderInBytes[i];
}
```

Comment: Вы хотите декомпилировать class-файл?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Главное получить классы из байтов, декомпилировать могу сам.

Comment: а как у Вас массив выглядит? много class файлов в одном массиве байтов -  друг за другом?

Comment: @dSH Я Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Расскажите подробнее откуда Вы взяли этот массив? Это один .class файл или несколько?

Comment: @defaultlocale этот массив был в исходниках одной C++ программы, которая использует JNI

Comment: Если говорить прямо та программа что в байтах работает не так как мне нужно, по этому мне надо немного переписать её.

Comment: Скорее всего этот массив без каких либо конвертаций можно записать в файл с расширением class, а потом скормить любому java-декомпилятору.

Comment: Т.е. нужно получить класс в виде файла с расширением class? Просто сохранить массив в файл нельзя?
try (FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(path)) {
    stream.write(bytes);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хорошо бы сначала разобраться что именно хранится в массиве: один там класс или несколько.

Если там один .class файл без зависимостей, то можно попробовать сделать так:

1. Записать байты в .class файл ([byte[] to file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350084/byte-to-file-in-java)).
2. Декомпилировать его одним из [декомпиляторов Java](https://habr.com/ru/post/176825/), например [JAD](https://varaneckas.com/jad/).

Надо заметить, что декомпиляторы не всегда идеально справляются с задачей и не вся информация сохраняется в байт-коде. Но для относительно простого класса можно получить результат.